# Display nodes in table format for the nodereference field on node add/edit forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-forms

I am developing a drupal 6.x site.

The scenario is, multiple students can be associated with a single tour. I have created two content types student and tour. Tour type uses a node reference field with "unlimited" number of values to choose students.

Further, I am using a view for the allowed values for that node reference field. I am also using "Table" style in that view to display the student nodes in a table on the Tour add/edit forms, however, the view is not showing up in table format instead its being displayed as unformatted fields while creating/editing Tour nodes. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the nodereference Explorer module in the past.  Along with making the user interface for selecting related nodes a lot nicer, it also allows you to customize the preview and use a 'table' format  http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_explorer